# Manually setting x and y axes in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, date, plot, time, plotly

Like the code given below, Can we set X and Y axes manually for date and time respectively in plotly.js??

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {range: [2, 5]},
  yaxis: {range: [2, 5]}
};

var layout = {
  xaxis: {range: ["2017-04-04", "2017-08-06"]},
  yaxis: {range: ["9:00:00", "24:00:00"]}
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.You can do something like this.

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    range: ['2017-04-04', '2017-08-06'],
    type: 'date'
  },
  yaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    range: [86.8700008333, 138.870004167],
    type: 'linear'
  }
};
```

ref : [Plotly JS Reference](https://plot.ly/javascript/time-series/)

Comment: think the yaxis should be autorange:false . though if range is provided it should override it appears. just a little confusing is all. https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-autorange